# jekyll: keep all files in the destination folder

Tags: jekyll

i have a mixed situation where i have my custom website generated in a `_dev` folder, and i want jekyll generated blog files to go in that same folder. of course i don't want jekyll to wipe up any of the files that are already there, but just to wipe up and rebuild the jekyll related files.

i don't want to list all the things i want to keep like this:

```
keep_files: [js,css,images,*.html]
```

plus the `*.html`, while building, throws an error. is there a way to tell jekyll to just wipe up and rebuild the jekyll related files only?

i can't find many options on this on the official documentation.

i'm on jekyll 3.4.3

Comment: This could really be improved.  I ended up here looking for a workaround for user uploaded images starting _ not being copied into site.  So I used gulp for this but it keeps getting overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

By default Jekyll deletes the output folder before building the site. Unless you change that behaviour in source code you can build your website in a temporal folder and copy the contents replacing the old files in your website folder.

```
jekyll build --destination /tmp/jk
cp -r /tmp/jk/* _dev/
```

This way it will only replace the Jekyll related files.